# Минимальный элемент коллекции по полю LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, коллекции

Хочу найти допустим минимальный элемент в списке по полю, но без циклов. LINQ Min возвращает мне не объект из коллекции, а тип поля, что логично (НЕТ!).

В с++ есть функции которые позволяют передать функцию по которой делать сравнение, и вернет  объект коллекции, что логично(ДА!).

Пример:

```
      class A
                {
                    public int x;
                    public int y;
                }

                 ...
          List<A> list = new List<A>();
                 ...

        //можно так
              int min = int.MaxValue;
                    A res;
                    foreach(var it in list)
                    {
                       if( it.x < min  )
                        {
                            min = it.x;
                            res = it;
                        }
                    }
        //или так(наверно, не проверял) но тут как бы уже два прохода по циклу.
                    int min1 = list.Min(it => it.x);
                    A res1 = list.Where(it => it.x == min1).First();
```

Есть что-то такое в C#? Внешние инструменты подключать нельзя.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько способов.

- Реализовать интерфейс `IComparable`:

  ```
  class A : IComparable<A>
  {
      public int x;
      public int y;

      public int CompareTo(A other)
      {
          return this.x.CompareTo(other.x);
      }
  }
  ```

  Теперь можно просто вызывать метод `Min()`:

  ```
  A min = list.Min();
  ```
- Использовать метод `Aggregate`.

  ```
  A min = list.Aggregate((a, b) => a.x < b.x ? a : b);
  ```

  Весьма любопытный способ, но неинтуитивный. При взгляде на такую конструкцию не просто понять, что именно она делает.

Answer (score 4):

Можно по-всякому.

Например, так:

```
list.OrderBy(a => a.x).First()
```

Или можно установить [MoreLinq из nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/), и писать просто

```
using MoreLinq;
```

```
list.MinBy(a => a.x)
```

Ну и если неохота подключать чужие библиотеки, недолго и самому написать:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static T MinBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, double> fun)
    {
        T result = default(T);
        double currmin = double.PositiveInfinity;
        bool first = true;
        foreach (var t in source)
        {
            double candidate = fun(t);
            if (first || candidate < currmin)
            {
                result = t;
                currmin = candidate;
                first = false;
            }
        }
        if (first)
            throw new ArgumentException("empty sequence at MinBy");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для информации:

Совсем без циклов написать не получится.
LINQ to Objects "за кулисами" вызывается те же ForEach и проходит по всем элементам коллекции, как если бы ты явно использовал циклы.

Другое дело, что все получается более лаконичным...

Comment: Для LINQ-to-objects вы правы, но для LINQ-to-database запрос уходит в базу.